# call yield in helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

The following results in a LocalJumpError (no block given to yield)

In Helper:

```
def yield_wrapper
  yield
end
```

In View:

```
<%= yield_wrapper %>
```

---

How would one go about something like this? I want to use it with sublayouts along the lines of:

```
<%= content_for?(:content) ? yield(:content) : yield %>
```

And I thought it would be nicer to call a helper method like:

```
<%= special_yield(:content) %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can.

`yield` expects a block, it is called to return a value to the code implementing the block. You're mixing up contexts with its use in layout files to inject content from erb files.

Besides, I think this is a bad idea. It doesn't seem necessary and seems like it'd create more code than it gets rid of.

Comment: Yeah not a big deal at all. I was just curious if it was possible